# Solving n-Queen problem using stack in java

Tags: java, data-structures, stack, n-queens

I have been trying to solve the n-queen problem using stacks in java. However the code runs infinitely and does not print out any solutions. Can anyone help me figure out what's going wrong?

```
public static void nQueen(int n){
    int currentPos = 0;
    Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>();
    while(true){
        if(currentPos < n){
            if(posChecker(stack, currentPos)){ // checking if curr pos is valid
                stack.push(currentPos);
                currentPos = 0;
            }
            else if(!posChecker(stack, currentPos)){ // if curr pos is invalid then doing following 
                if(stack.isEmpty())
                    break;
                else{
                    currentPos = stack.pop();
                    currentPos += 1;
                }
            }
            else if(stack.getSize() == n){ //to print out the queens
                for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
                    for(int k=0; k<n; k++){
                        if(k == stack.peek()){
                            System.out.print("Q ");
                            currentPos = stack.pop()+1;
                        }
                        else System.out.print("* ");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public static boolean posChecker(Stack<Integer> s, int i){
    if(!s.isEmpty()){
        if(s.peek() == i) return false;
        else if(s.peek() == i-1) return false;
        else if(s.peek() == i+1) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: What `n` do you start with?

Comment: well i started off with 4, and its running infinitely @akuzminykh

Answer (score 0):

in **if-else** costruction only one branch executes.
When **if posChecker(stack, currentPos)** retuns *false* **else** branch of **if(posChecker(stack, currentPos)** statement executes.
In that branch you have another **if-else** construction:
**if (!posChecker(stack, currentPos)) {} else ...**
**if(stack.getSize() == n)** is in **else** branch.

**else if(stack.getSize() == n){ //to print out the queens** <- this branch never run because *posChecker* always returns false in that line:
**else if(!posChecker(stack, currentPos)){ // if curr pos is invalid then doing following**

Comment: i dont quite get this. For printing the queens, its just doing that based on the stack. It doesnt call the posChecker method to print the queens